# Caching method, cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp

i wish use cache user_info() method.
Address: mypage.com/user_info/1, mypage.com/user_info/2 and so on...

Code:

```
var $helpers = array('Cache');

var $cacheAction = array(
    'user_info/*' => '60'
 );
```

But cache not work. What I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable it in your config?

> http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1379/Cache-Helper-Configuration
>   To use the cache helper in any view or controller, you must first uncomment and set Configure::Cache.check to true in core.php of your app/config folder. If this is not set to true, then the cache will not be checked or created.

You need to have this value in your Core config:

```
Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
```

Comment: Remove the '*' after your action.  How long are you trying to cache for and how are you testing it?